# Converting str numbers in list to int and find out the sum of the list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, sum

I have a list, but the numbers in it are strings so I can't find the sum of the list, so I need help in converting the numbers in the list to int.

This is my code

```
def convertStr(cals):
    ret = float(cals)
return ret
TotalCal = sum(cals)
```

So basically there is list called `cals`
and it looks like this

```
 (20,45,...etc)
```

But the numbers in it are strings so when I try finding the sum like this

```
TotalCal = sum(cals)
```

And then run it shows an error saying that the list needs to be an int format
so the question is how do I convert all numbers in the `list` to int format?

If you have a different way of finding the sum of lists it will be good too.

Comment: Does `cals` only hold integers?

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the python builtin [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) or a list comprehension for this

```
def convertStr(cals):
    ret = [float(i) for i in (cals)]
    return ret
```

or

```
def convertStr(cals):
    return map(float,cals)
```

Here are the `timeit` results for both the approaches

```
$ python -m timeit "cals = ['1','2','3','4'];[float(i) for i in (cals)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.804 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "cals = ['1','2','3','4'];map(float,cals)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.787 usec per loop
```

As you can see `map` is faster and more pythonic as compared to the list comprehension. This is discussed in full length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/4099593)

> map may be microscopically faster in some cases (when you're NOT making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map and a listcomp). List comprehensions may be faster in other cases

---

Another way using [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap). This is the *fastest* for long lists

```
from itertools import imap
TotalCal = sum(imap(float,cals)
```

And using `timeit` for a list with 1000 entries.

```
$ python -m timeit "import random;cals = [str(random.randint(0,100)) for r in range(1000)];sum(map(float,cals))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import random;cals = [str(random.randint(0,100)) for r in range(1000)];[float(i) for i in (cals)]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "from itertools import imap;import random;cals = [str(random.randint(0,100)) for r in range(1000)];imap(float,cals)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 msec per loop
```

As Padraic [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869396/i-need-help-converting-str-numbers-in-list-to-int-so-i-can-find-out-the-sum-of-t/29869412?noredirect=1#comment47865102_29869412) below, The `imap` way is the best way to go! It is fast<sup>1</sup> and looks great! Inclusion of a library function has it's bearing on small lists only and not on large lists. Thus for large lists, `imap` is better suited.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>List comprehension is still slower than `map` by 1 micro second!!! Thank god</sub>

Comment: create a large list for testing and include itertools.imap

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Nice idea of using, `imap`, but however the OP wants a list, so it will have an additional call to `list`. Thus the speed of an iterator will be useless :(

Comment: for a large list I bet it will still be faster so will `sum(imap(float,cals))`

Comment: Aargh, I missed the OP's last statement *if you have a different way of finding the sum of lists it will be good too*. I will add imap results asap ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Spot on! Rite in the middle of the bulls eye. It **IS** the fastest

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(map(float,cals))
```

or

```
sum(float(i) for i in cals)
```

Comment: this multiplied the numbers together not add together